# Is $\mathbb Z_1$ a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$\mathbb Z_1 = \{0, 1\} \subseteq \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\} = \mathbb Z_{10}.$

Since $0 + 1 = 1$, $1 + 0 = 1$ and $1 + 1 = 0$, the identity in $\mathbb Z_1$ is $0$ and the inverse element is $1.$ Since $0 + 1 \in \mathbb Z_1$, the set $\mathbb Z_1$ is closed under addition. Therefore $\mathbb Z_1$ is a subgroup $\mathbb Z_{10}.$ Does that check out?

Comment: $\{0, 1\} = \mathbb Z_2$. $\quad\mathbb Z_1$ would be the trivial group, with identity for addition as its only element: $\{0\}$

Comment: Is that how the problem is stated in the source?

Comment: The problem is stated as "list all the cyclic subgroups of $<\mathbb Z_{10}, +>.$ I was trying to check every subgroup manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, $\mathbb{Z}_1$ would be defined as $\{0\}$ if it were ever used. What you are referring to is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Second, your proof is not correct. The $0$ and $1$ in the first group are completely unrelated to the $0$ and $1$ in the second group. The subset $\{0,1\}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is not a subgroup because for example $1+1=2$ is outside the set.

There is also a bit of abuse of notation going on here which can lead to confusion. These elements are not actually numbers, they are congruence classes of integers. To denote elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ it is perhaps most correct to write $[0]_2$ and $[1]_2$ and elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ could be written $[3]_{10}$ etc. to emphasize that these are not numbers but rather congruence classes modulo an integer. This way congruence classes modulo different integers would be less likely to be confused with each other.

Comment: Does the subgroup of $\mathbb Z_n$ have to contain all the elements in $\mathbb Z_n$?

Comment: @algebra No. For example, $\{0,5\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ because it is closed under addition and taking inverses. $0+5=5+0=5$ and $5+5=0+0=0$.

Comment: @ Matt Samuel, are $\mathbb Z_2 = \{0, 1\} = \{0, 5\}$?

Comment: @algebra The subgroup $\{0,5\}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, with an isomorphism given by $0\mapsto 0$ and $1\mapsto 5$. They are not actually the same, though, even though their group structure is.

Comment: @ Matt Samuel, $1 + 1 = 2$ because that's how it is in $\mathbb Z_{10}$, in other words when we do clock arithmetic here, we do that inside  $\mathbb Z_{10},$ not any other set and check if the sum is inside the subset(would-be subgroup) of $\mathbb Z_{10}.$ That's why $\{0, 5\}$ is a subgroup since in $\mathbb Z_{10}, 5 + 5 = 0$ and $0 \in \{0, 5\}$. Correct?

Comment: @algebra That is why $\{0,5\}$ is closed under addition, yes. To show that it is a subgroup you also have to show that inverses are contained in it.